# Control Assembly add reference

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dll, class-library

Suppose that i have a ".dll" file genereared from a class library and i want this class library to be referenced by certain projects that i have but if someone else wants to reference that class library to his own projects he won't be able to do that, it's like a control on who can can use this library.

Is there a way to achieve that in Microsoft .Net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following questions explain how to do what you're asking:

[How to forbid a .NET DLL class library to be referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323339/how-to-forbid-a-net-dll-class-library-to-be-referenced)

[How to prevent others from using my .Net assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96624/how-to-prevent-others-from-using-my-net-assembly)

[How do I prevent my .Net dll from being added as a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161977/how-do-i-prevent-my-net-dll-from-being-added-as-a-reference)

I hope this helps.

PS: I would add this as a comment, but I'm currently unable to.